# Memory friendlier ArrayList<double []> convertion to 2D array double

Tags: java, memory, type-conversion

A question about performance and memory allocation. I have a code that returns a `ArrayList<double[]>` and I want to convert to `double[][]`. The question is since I have to get the dimensions of the 2D array the second approach which does not have an intermediate variable (`features`) created is it more memory friendly?

To be more specific `lbpFeatures.getFeatures().size()` and `lbpFeatures.getFeatures().get(0).length` run this method twice (plus 1 for the initial assignment that is `LBPdescriptions = lbpFeatures.getFeatures()` part) or java is smart enough to just execute it once (as it is the intended by me approach) and determine the dimension from there?

```
//first approach
        List<double[]> features = lbpFeatures.getFeatures();
        LBPdescriptions = features.toArray(new double[features.size()][features.get(0).length]);

//second approach        
        LBPdescriptions = lbpFeatures.getFeatures().toArray(new double[lbpFeatures.getFeatures().size()][lbpFeatures.getFeatures().get(0).length]);
```

Comment: If there is a difference, I don't expect it to be present very long once the JIT compiler gets to it. Also, in terms of memory the only difference is the creation of a reference, which takes up 32 or 64 bits if memory serves. So the difference is essentially insignificant.

Comment: Those would be entirely equivalent in practice, save that neither of them are as efficient as they could be: you should use `new double[features.size()][]`.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman if that is true then there should be a call 3 times in the `lbpFeatures.getFeatures()` method. Is that the case? Otherwise the only drawback I see is that the implicit calculation of the second dimension by java is faster than my explicit one. You are referring to this?

Comment: a) None of these versions will call `getFeatures()` more than _once_, including my suggestion.  b) Your version will create the empty rows of the array and then _discard_ them, not fill them; my suggestion will avoid that completely unnecessary allocation.

Comment: So a temporary array is created in my case! That's why I often see (in the 1D version) `toArray(new double[0])`? Thanks and I was wondering why is that.